# 2D pixel array rotation and scaling

Tags: c#, image, matrix, rotation, image-scaling

I am working on a C# program to process images ( given as int[,] )..

I have a 2D array of pixels, and I need to rotate them around a point, then scale them down to fit the original array. I already found articles about using matrix to transform to a point and rotate then transform back. What remains is to scale the resultant image to fit an array of original size.

How that can be done? (preferably  with 2 equations one for x and one for y )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RotationMatrix.html). That should give you all the math behind doing coordinate rotations.

Comment: he'll need a good interpolation algorithm though if he doesn't want his images to look a mess

Comment: Yes, though he's also interested in doing scaling on the rotated image -- this will take care of the interpolation part of it.

Answer (score 2):

In the **[Matrix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.matrix_members.aspx)** class you have both functions **[Rotate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.matrix.rotate.aspx)**(At) and **[Scale](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.matrix.scale.aspx)**. What other would you find out?

Answer (score 1):

You need to find a transform from the resultant array to the original image. You then transform points in the destination to points in the source image and copy. Anti-aliasing via oversampling is also an option. Your rotation matrix can also apply a scaling - just multiply the matrix by the scale factor (this assumes a 2x2). If you're doing 3x3 matrix for rotation, scaling, and translation, then just multiply the upper left 2x2 by the scale factor.

Lastly, at the risk of some humility here is a link to some old TP6/asm DOS code I wrote for doing full screen roto-zooming. Strange the stuff that sticks around on the net:
http://www.hornet.org/cgi-bin/scene-search.cgi?search=Paul%20H.%20Kahler

Comment: +1 Interesting method you've opted for in your rotozoomer (your method no. 4 mentioned in the readme).

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need to do can be done with `Bitmap` images in GDI+ (using the `System.Drawing...` namespaces).  These classes are designed and optimized for doing exactly this sort of thing (image manipulation).  Is there any particular reason you can't work with an actual `Bitmap` instead of an `int[,]`?  You could even write a very simple routine to create a `Bitmap` from an `int[,]`, do whatever you need to to on the `Bitmap`, and then convert it back to `int[,]` at the end.